# Salesforce Embedded Service Web Chat not connecting to agents

Tags: service, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, livechat

We are deploying the Messaging for in-app and web service to an external website. I've followed the set-up instructions and can see the web chat on a external website and experience site but it will not show an agent as being available.

I've been through the help https://[help.salesforce.com](https://help.salesforce.com/s/article/articleView?id=000383003@type=1) but still the issue persists.

WHen inspecting the page i can see the following error message *[EmbeddedServiceBootstrap] Warning: EmbeddedService Messaging Bootstrap may not function correctly with this native JS function modified: document.addEventListener*

Is this the cause of the problem?

I tried the following

1. https://[help.salesforce.com](https://help.salesforce.com/s/article/articleView?id=000383003@type=1)